# How do you add data to a model's has_many relationship programatically in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In this app I have three models - Players, Teams and Rounds.

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :players
  belongs_to :round
end

class Round < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams
end
```

In each round, a different amount of teams will be generated based on the number of players that are sent in (Players are to be persistent, but in each round you can select the ones that will actually play this time around). Once the teams are created, they are populated with the list of players for this round.

In my RoundsController i've setup a method which gets called in the create action for a new Round.

```
def createTeams
  totalPlayers = @players.length
  noOfTeams = totalPlayers/5

  while (noOfTeams > 0) do
    team = Team.new
    team.round = @round
    team.save
    noOfTeams -= 1
  end

  i = totalPlayers - 1

  while (i >= 0) do
    @round.teams.each do |team|
      player = @players.at(i)
      player.team = team
      player.save
      i -= 1
  end
end
```

At the moment I can't actually set the team's round to the current round, I get a 'can't write unknown attribute `round_id`' error. Am I going about this the right way? Have I setup my relationships correctly? I thought I would be able to do something like @round.teams.build(team) or @round.teams.add(team)... Any help appreciated, sorry if this is a duplicate but I've been searching around for a while without any luck.

Here's the Schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150310124456) do

create_table "players", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "first_name"
  t.string   "surname"
  t.string   "email"
  t.string   "phone"
  t.integer  "goals"
  t.integer  "clean_sheets"
  t.integer  "wins"
  t.integer  "draws"
  t.integer  "losses"
  t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
end

create_table "players_teams", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "player_id"
  t.integer "team_id"
end

add_index "players_teams", ["player_id"], name:    "index_players_teams_on_player_id"
add_index "players_teams", ["team_id"], name:  "index_players_teams_on_team_id"

create_table "rounds", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "teams", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

end
```

Comment: Does Team actually have a round_id attribute?

Comment: What does your schema look like?

Comment: I've added the schema, and no it doesn't Swards

Comment: belongs_to requires the foreign key, it's looking for it.  In your migration, you'll need to add that column to Team, then it will work.

Comment: You probably cannot do `player.team = team` as well. Maybe `player.teams << team`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `round_id` from Team.

In a migration you can simply use

`add_column :teams, :round_id, :integer`

to fix this. An id like this is required if you have a `belongs_to` in a model.

And to add to a round

`@round.teams << team`